# AudioBufferSourceNode: index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm following [a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API) on the WebAudio API, but instead of a gain node, I would like to use an `AudioBufferSourceNode` (to adjust playback rates).

But connecting a track to the `AudioBufferSourceNode` throws an error message and complains:

```
IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
```

Here is my code:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
const bufferNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioContext, { playbackRate: 0.9 });

track.connect(bufferNode).connect(audioContext.destination);
```

The HTML contains this script and an audio tag with example audio. I've based it on the files from the tutorial as well, you can find a [repo of them online here](https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples).

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're getting is thrown because an `AudioBufferSourceNode` only has an output. It doesn't accept any inputs. Which means the following pseudo code will always throw an error.

```
someAudioNode.connect(anAudioBufferSourceNode);
```

An `AudioBufferSourceNode` expects to be fed with an `AudioBuffer` which can be thought of as its input.

One solution to your problem would be to load the file that you use as `src` of the `AudioElement` upfront, decode it with `decodeAudioData()` and then use the resulting `AudioBuffer` with an `AudioBufferSourceNode`.

Or you could not use the Web Audio API at all and instead use the [`playbackRate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playbackRate) property of the AudioElement to adjust the playback rate.

The downside of the first solution is that you need to download the entire file upfront. In contrast to that the second solution is less accurate. It's for example not possible to automate the `playbackRate` of an `AudioElement` whereas it could be done with the `playbackRate` of an `AudioBufferSourceNode`.